# Reference request for bounds of $n$-th composite

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, big-list

### **Motivation**

I will briefly elaborate here my motivations for asking the question. If you are not interested in it then please go to the questions.

1. Recently during trying to understand and prove the [Second Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture), I came to notice that the following slightly weak version of the conjecture,

   > $π(x + y) ≤ π(x) + π(y)$ for all **integers** $x, y ≥ 2$, where $π(x)$ denotes the prime-counting function, giving the number of prime numbers up to and including $x$.

   Is equivalent to the following,

   > $π(x + y) ≤ π(x) + π(y)$ for all **composite number** $x, y ≥ 4$, where $π(x)$ denotes the prime-counting function, giving the number of prime numbers up to and including $x$.

   Which in turn is equivalent to the following,

   > $c_m+c_n\ge c_{m+n+1}$ for all $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ where $c_j$ denotes the $j$-th composite.
2. It can be easily seen that the following results hold,

   - If $c_n$ and $c_m$ denotes respectively the $n$-th and $m$-th composite number such that $m+n$ is even and $c_n+c_m$ is odd, then there exists a prime between $c_n$ and $c_m$
   - If $c_n$ and $c_m$ denotes respectively the $n$-th and $m$-th composite number such that $m+n$ is odd and $c_n+c_m$ is even, then there exists a prime between $c_n$ and $c_m$ for all sufficiently large $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$.
   - For all sufficiently $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ either there exists a prime between $x$ and $y$ or $\pi(x)+\pi(y)>\pi(x+y)$.
3. The literature regarding the bounds on $n$-th composite number seems to be very little. In fact, by online search I found no other paper (in English) than    [this](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/027_01_JIPAM/027_01_www.pdf).

### **Question**

Does there exist stronger bounds for the $n$-th composite than the one already given in the paper I linked above? More specifically, Does there exist stronger bounds for the $n$-th composite than what is already given in the following theorem?

> For all integer $n\ge 4$ we have, $$n\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\ln n}+\dfrac{1}{\ln^2 n}\right)<c_n< n\left(1+\dfrac{1}{\ln n}+\dfrac{3}{\ln^2 n}\right)$$

If so then can someone please give some references?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I doubt there's anything better in the literature. Certainly MathSciNet doesn't show any better paper citing the one you linked to—which uses exactly the techniques I would expect for this (not very central) problem.

Comment: Finding bounds on the $n$th composite is equivalent to finding bounds on the $n$th prime, no? Lots of papers about that.

Comment: Which problem are you talking about @GregMartin?

Comment: You should edit your post to be more specific about the bounds you are citing; then we can be more specific about our responses, and you won't have to guess.

Comment: @GregMartin: Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the question. If there is anything else that I can do for more clarification, please let me know.

Comment: Can anyone explain the reason for downvote?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Would you mind to elaborate a proof of the statement that  finding bounds on the $n$th composite is equivalent to finding bounds on the $n$th prime?